# C++ | Show progress bar with curl?

Tags: c++, windows, curl, libcurl

I am wondering how can I add a progress bar for curl, below is my code, it works 100% I just want to know how to add a progress bar (C++) maybe like 10% > 30% > 100% (WINDOWS OS)

```
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;

char *url= "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "./ATNA/5MB.zip";


curl_version_info_data * vinfo = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca-bundle.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: from `write_data` post `PBM_SETRANGE32` and `PBM_SETPOS` messages to your progress bar window

Comment: There is an xferinfo callback https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html

Comment: Here is an example of showing progress bar https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smooth-gtk-thread.html

Comment: You can use multi threaded approach to what ever you are using as windows front end, windows-form or WPF for creating a progress bar, and adding the value of it form the mentioned example.

Comment: @RbMm _error: macro "curl_easy_setopt" passed 5 arguments, but takes just 3_

Comment: @RbMm Have an example of that ?